# sms messaging service twilio

Tags: sms, twilio

I need to send an sms to a user and this user should reply to the sms, in my database I will have to link the answer to the message id that triggered the first sms I sended.

The way I understand how twilio and sms work there is no possibility of metadata transmission to make this exchange totally unique.

So I could use cookies or a messaging service with multiple twilio phone numbers with a 15 min timeout. So I won't keep waiting for an answer.

My question is what should be the most simple and cheapest way to make it work, is there an add-on or tools that would help ?

lets say there is a big event and it make me send 10 uniques messages in a 5min timeframe to the same guy, and i need to get back 10 uniques responses. I will have to already own 10 phones numbers just in case ?

Messaging services only work with unique phone numbers ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, you will need 10 unique numbers to track 10 unique responses.  But remember that those twilio numbers can be reused with queries to other customers phones.

```
Twilio Number 1 -> Client 1's Phone = Unique Pair
Twilio Number 1 -> Client 2's Phone = Unique Pair
Twilio Number 2 -> Client 1's Phone = Unique Pair
```

So with this, if you have 100 customers you still only need 2 Twilio numbers to track 2 unique responses from each client by looking at the response to and from phone numbers.

Also, don't forget that you can use the api to buy phone numbers:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers, so in the above example, if you need a third unique response your app could purchase a number in real time, and send a message using that new number.  Then your app would be able to track 3 responses from that point on (just don't forget to put some sort of a sanity check in their so you don't end up buying hundreds of numbers, unless you are profitable, then Twilio can scale to as big as you can dream!)

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure I work at Till Mobile.

I believe you can achieve this using our A2P SMS platform and a single number.

Till creates a unique id for the to and from phone number combination when an outbound message is sent.

When an inbound message is received it is tagged with the same unique id. In the Till API this id is called the *project_launch_guid*.

**Using the Till API**

You can get a free *username* and *api_key* via https://tillmobile.com/

**Send the outbound message**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{
  "phone": ["phone_number"],
  "questions" : [{
      "text": "Server is on fire. Please respond with guidance!",
      "webhook": "http://requestb.in/1ilpbfd1"
  }]
}' "https://platform.tillmobile.com/api/send?username=username&api_key=api_key"
```

Which returns

```
{
    "project_launch_guid": "some_guid",
    ...
}
```

Each send is treated like a session. They persist indefinitely unless another send is created with the same to and from phone numbers. In that case the second send is queued behind the first and a configurable TTL (Defaults to 1 hour) is set for the first if a response it not received in which case we pop the next message off the queue and immediately deliver

**Retrieve the inbound message**

If a user later responds the message will be POST'd to the webhook defined above in this format including the same *project_launch_guid* returned from the send:

```
{
    "project_launch_guid": "some_guid",
    "participant_guid": "585897f2-2c30-43f5-8f6b-7c243e8ac4b0",
    "participant_phone_number": "phone_number",
    "question_guid": "685897f2-2c30-43f5-8f6b-7c243e8ac4b0",
    "question_text": "Server is on fire. Please respond with guidance!",
    "result_guid": "885897f2-2c30-43f5-8f6b-7c243e8ac4b0",
    "result_timestamp": "2016-11-27T11:57:14.060474",
    "result_answer": "Find the fire extinguisher stat",
    ...
}
```

Note: the webhook is optional. If it is not provided the inbound message can be retrieved via our results API:

```
curl "https://platform.tillmobile.com/api/results?username=username&api_key=api_key&project_launch_guid=some_guid"
```

Using either the webhook or results API the *project_launch_guid* can be used to tie the outbound and inbound messages together. The result_answer attribute value will contain the user's inbound message.

We have more documentation available here https://till.readme.io/docs/

Don't hesitate to let me know how we can assist further.